# google sheets, get all sheet names where cell "A1" doesn't have a certain string

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a very large google sheets file with lots of sheets, and i need a list of sheets where a cell doesn't have a string "description". Some sheets are missing it, or it is on a wrong cell, and those i need to find to fix those sheets. I can't figure out how to extend this code i found here. I'm very new to google sheets.

```
/*** return sheet names for active document
 * @customfunction
 */
function sheetName() {
  var out = new Array()
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
  return out 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### To check a single cell:

```js
function checkCell() {
  let value = "description" // edit this for your value
  let file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheet = file.getActiveSheet(); // gets your active sheet
 
  // gets value from cell A1
  let valueToCheck = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue()

  // Checking value
  if(valueToCheck != value) {
    // if NOT right value, print "FALSE"
    Logger.log("FALSE")
  }
}
```

#### To make it check all sheets:

```js
function checkSheets() {
  let value = "description" // edit this for your value
  let file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheets = file.getSheets(); // gets all sheets in array
 
  let numberOfSheets = sheets.length // gets number of sheets in total
  
  let result = []; // initialize empty array
  
  // for loop to run as many times as there are number of sheets
  for (let i=0; i<numberOfSheets; i++) {
    
    // Getting value from sheet cell A1
    let valueToCheck = sheets[i].getRange("A1").getValue()

    // Checking value
    if(valueToCheck != value) {
      // if NOT right value, get sheet name
      let name = sheets[i].getName()
      // Add to result array
      result.push(name);
    }
  }
  
  // Print sheets without right value to console
  Logger.log(result)
}
```

Copy this into your script editor, run it, and then go to View > Logs.

#### References & Further Reading

- [Apps Script Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/fundamentals-codelabs?hl=en)
- [Spreadsheet Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet?hl=en)
- [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)
- [range object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

```
function findAll() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const shts=ss.getSheets();
  let f=[];
  shts.forEach(sh=>{
    if(sh.getRange("A1").getValue()=="Description") {
      f.push(sh.getName());
    }
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(f.join('<br />'),"Sheets with String in A1")
}
```